# How to call a function in discord.py bot when script starts but not when bot is re-logging in?

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

if you have a discord.py bot sometimes the bot goes offline and logs in again. Thats not really a problem but i want my script to automatically call a function when it started im now using on_ready(). like this:

```py
global restockkk
restockkk = False

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    logchannel = bot.get_channel(ID_CHANNEL)
    await logchannel.send(f'Logged in as {bot.user}'.format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Buddy is busy being the GOAT"))
    await restock()
```

restock is the name of my function. but when it logs in again it runs the function again, this results in the function running like 40 times after a day which is insane spam. I tried setting a global restockkk that sets to true when the restock() function is run but i think the script just starts over again or something because it ignores the restockkk set to true in the restock() function and still runs if i use:

```py
global restockkk
restockkk = False

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    logchannel = bot.get_channel(ID_CHANNEL)
    await logchannel.send(f'Logged in as {bot.user}'.format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Buddy is busy being the GOAT"))
    if not restockkk:
        await restock()
```

this is my restock function:

```py
async def restock():
        logchannel = bot.get_channel(960147355691253800)
        await logchannel.send('Restock monitor on')
        restockkk = True
        while True:
            try:
                if not restockkk:
                    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Buddy is busy being the GOAT"))
                    break
                #... first piece of code
                await asyncio.sleep(120)
                #... second piece of code
                await asyncio.sleep(120)
            except Exception:
                await logchannel.send('exception occurred')
                await restock()
```

(its an infinite loop). The above sadly didn't work, i run my bot with:

```
bot.run(MY_BOT_TOKEN)
```

I also have a stop command (that's why i use global restockkk)

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
    async def stop(message):
        if message.author.id == myId:
            restockkk = False
            await message.channel.send('Restock monitor is off')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You are not allowed to use this command')
```

So my question is: how can i call a function when the bot starts for the **first** time and not when its on_ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`bot.setup_hook()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=setup_hook#discord.ext.commands.Bot.setup_hook), which is only called once when running the script. `on_ready` is disfavored for the exact reason you are running into - it's not only called once.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of how to use setup_hook()? I use `intents=intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = intents)` and `bot.run('token')` i tried [this](https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/discord-py-setup-hook-with-code-examples/) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answer by Grace, `on_ready` is called multiple times and **you should use `setup_hook` for things that should only run once on startup**. However, there's more issues going on here.

You seem to misunderstand how the `global` keyword works. There's no point in using it at the top of your file, you should use it inside of `functions` where you want to *modify* the value of variables outside of the current scope. AKA, in your `restock` function.

By not using `global` inside of `restock`, you're just creating a local variable inside of that function instead of changing the value of that global variable, meaning that `restockkk` is always `False`.

```py
global restockkk  # This doesn't do anything
restockkk = False

async def restock():
   ...
   restockkk = True  # This doesn't modify restockkk, it creates a local variable inside of the restock()-function

async def stop(...):
   ...
   restockkk = False  # This doesn't modify restockkk, it creates a local variable inside of the stop()-function
```

To modify a variable in a higher scope, use the `global` keyword *inside of the function where you want to modify it*.

```py
restockkk = False

async def restockkk():
    global restockkk  # Use it inside of the function instead
    restockkk = True  # This does modify it
```

Additionally

- **Don't change presence in `on_ready`**
- Preferably, don't do *anything at all* in `on_ready`
- Instead of an infinite `while True:` loop, look into [`ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)